# Accessing a private data member from within a member function

Tags: c++, scope, private, member

In a file named maze.hpp (a header file) I have the following:

```
class Maze
{
    public:
        Maze(int size);
        ~Maze() {}

        void step();

    private:

        int exitRow;    
};
```

In another file named maze.cpp I have the following:

```
void step(){

    this.exitRow = 3;

}

int main(){
    Maze maze(4);
    maze.step();
}
```

This gives an error: `invalid use of 'this' outside of a non-static member function`

step is a member function of `Maze`. How can I access the data members of an instance of `Maze` from within one of its member functions?

Answer (score 3):

When you define a function outside of the class declaration, you are required to provide the class name like this:

```
void Maze::step(){

    exitRow = 3;

}
```

The compiler has no other way of knowing where the method that you're defining belongs.

Note that there is no need to use `this` when referring to members from a member function. `this` is still available and technically writing something like the following is valid: `this->exitRow = 3;`, but unnecessary. Also, `this` is a pointer (hence the usage of operator `->` rather than `.`).

Answer (score 3):

The lines

```
void step(){    
    this.exitRow = 3;
}
```

define a global function, not a member function of `Maze`. Also, `this.exitRow` is the wrong syntax. You need:

```
void Maze::step(){
    this->exitRow = 3;
}
```

Comment: This seems to uncover a bigger problem. I followed your above suggestion, and now I get:

`Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Maze::Maze(int)", referenced from:
      _main in maze-780529.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Comment: You've to define `Maze::Maze(int size)` too. You can define it inline by using `Maze(int size) : exitRow(0) {}` or in the .cpp file by using `Maze::Maze(int size) : exitRow(0) {}`. I don't know how `size` is related to `exitRow`. You'll have to figure that out.

Answer (score 2):

Your function definition should be:

```
void Maze::step()
{

}
```

The way it is now, it just defines a free standing function that does not belong to any class.
Also, `this` is a pointer so you need to access members by dereferencing it using `->`. And it is good to note that you do not need to use `this->exitRow` to refer `exitRow`, merely mentioning `exitRow` inside the member function will serve the same purpose.

Comment: This seems to uncover a bigger problem. I am compiling using g++ maze.cpp, but I get `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Maze::Maze(int)", referenced from:
      _main in maze-0e50e8.o`

Any idea what I can do now?

Comment: @DavidoWidre: You have not defined the constructor which takes a `int` parameter. you need to define `Maze::Maze(int)`.